# Actionscript problems

Tags: flash, compiler-construction, actionscript

Hi i am fairly new to actionscript and i am currently having some problems. Even though i have added the stop();, the swf movie keeps relooping. I am also getting some errors from the compiler which are : *Access of undefined property Startbtn_ins and Access of undefined property gotoStartbtn* Even though i have put my actions in a different layer, my button is called Start_btn and is already converted. Thus when i click my button, it does not go to the frame i want it to and just stays there.
  Here is my Actionscript code :

```
`stop();`

Startbtn_ins.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoStartbtn);

function gotoButt1(event:MouseEvent):void

{
    gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one actually you have wrote the function name with mouse event are 
 **gotoStartbtn** but in the function you have given different name called 
 **gotoButt1**. So Please give the correct name for the function here i mentioned 
 like you do then it will work.

```
stop();

Startbtn_ins.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoStartbtn);

function gotoStartbtn(event:MouseEvent):void

 {
   gotoAndPlay(2);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm not sure if it is intentionally but `stop();` must not be in quotes.

Second you have to get rid of all errors for stop() to actually work. You can not have any errors in your code.

The error
Access of undefined property Startbtn_ins
and
Access of undefined property gotoStartbtn
means that actionscript can not see instaces with that name.

It might be because of several reasons. Most common, however:
 1. Check that you have given symbol an instance name Startbtn_ins in flash object property panel.
 2. Check that object is at available at the frame you have entered the code. So, if you have your Startbtn_ins.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoStartbtn); at the 1st frame, then object with that name also needs to be available at that frame.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I can see it, there is a stray character before stop();
and you might now be aware that the function gotoButt1() will not be triggered since 
`Startbtn_ins.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoStartbtn);` where gotoStartbtn should be gotoButt1